# I can't figure out how to stop my navigation bar from highlighting my active link when I hover over it

Tags: html, css

For a school project, I'm making a website with a navigation bar and I have the bar so that when I'm on a page, the link is highlighted in the navigation bar. But when ever I hover over that active bar, it changes colour because of my `.hover` attribute on my css for the non active links. How do I stop this from happening?

I've tried

```
li a:hover .active {
   background-colour: DarkBlue;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I cant figure out anything else that might work.

Here is my code.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: Gray;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: 111;
}

.active {
  background-color: DarkBlue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="life-on-iss.html">Life on the ISS</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Details</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="why-was-it-built.html">Why it was built.</a>
        <a href="what-skills-do-I-need-to-work-here.html">What skills do I need to work here?</a>
        <a href="what-we-have-learnt.html">What we have learnt.</a>
      </div>
      <li style="float:right"><a class="activefloatright" href="#about">Assignment</a></li>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Can someone tell me the correct code for solving this problem? Hopefully I've been clear enough with this request. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li .active:hover {
   background-colour: DarkBlue;
}
```

Comment: I added this to my css and it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JaydenCollis try to change "colour" to "color" and it will work :)

Comment: Ok yes! It works but now its showing up with the cursor for text selecting/editing whenever I hover over the text. Is it something in the css that's making it do that or just my computer? Sorry if I sound pushy.

Comment: That is what is suposed to be doing on hovering. Every time you hover over an element with active class that is inside li element it will change its color